# Popping TitledPane content out to window

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, accordion

I'm trying to get a UI behavior of an accordion in which the user can pop out any `TitledPane` to a window, and pop the window back into a `TitledPane` inside the accordion.

However, when popping out a collapsed `TitledPane` the content isn't aligned properly in the `Stage`, and if the no pane is expanded it won't even show at all.

Attached is a minimal example showing the problem - note that I'm keeping two placeholder panes to avoid having the content node (A `VBox` in my case) be in the Scene Graph more than once. I have tried setting `preferredSize` and `visible` properties on the `VBox` and also calling `layout` before and after showing, and even programmatically expanding the titled pane, but nothing seems to work.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TitledPane t1 = new TitledPane();
        TitledPane t2 = new TitledPane();
        Accordion accordion = new Accordion(t1, t2);
        t1.setContent(buildComponent("Pane 1", t1, accordion));
        t2.setContent(buildComponent("Pane 2", t2, accordion));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(accordion, 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private VBox buildComponent(String name, TitledPane titledPane, Accordion holder) {
        final Button popout = new Button("Pop out");
        titledPane.setGraphic(popout);
        titledPane.setText(name);
        final VBox component = new VBox(new Label(name), new TableView<>());
        final Pane placeholder1 = new Pane();
        final Pane placeholder2 = new Pane();
        Stage st = new Stage();
        st.setScene(new Scene(placeholder1, 300, 300));

        popout.setOnAction(event -> {
            if (!st.equals(component.getScene().getWindow())) {
                holder.getPanes().remove(titledPane);
                titledPane.setContent(placeholder2);
                st.getScene().setRoot(component);
                st.show();
            }
        });

        st.setOnHidden(windowEvent -> {
            st.getScene().setRoot(placeholder1);
            titledPane.setContent(component);
            holder.getPanes().add(titledPane);
        });

        return component;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Illustrations of results:
Result when no pane is expanded:
[image: Result when no pane is expanded]
Result when other pane is expanded. Note how the label is not visible:
[image: Result when other pane is expanded. Note how the label is not visible.]
Result when pane is expanded - this is the result I want to have in all cases:
[image: Result when pane is expanded - this is the result I want to have in all cases.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more playing around I've found a way to circumvent this problem, by using `AnchorPane`s instead of directly setting the `Stage`'s root and the `TitledPane`'s content:

```
private VBox buildComponent(String name, TitledPane titledPane, Accordion holder) {
    final Button popout = new Button("Pop out");
    titledPane.setGraphic(popout);
    titledPane.setText(name);
    final VBox component = new VBox(new Label(name), new TableView<>());
    final AnchorPane placeholder1 = new AnchorPane();
    final AnchorPane placeholder2 = new AnchorPane();
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(component, 0D);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(component, 0D);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(component, 0D);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(component, 0D);
    Stage st = new Stage();
    st.setScene(new Scene(placeholder1, 300, 300));
    titledPane.setContent(placeholder2);
    placeholder2.getChildren().add(component);

    popout.setOnAction(event -> {
        if (!st.equals(component.getScene().getWindow())) {
            holder.getPanes().remove(titledPane);
            placeholder2.getChildren().clear();
            placeholder1.getChildren().add(component);
            st.show();
        }
    });

    st.setOnHidden(windowEvent -> {
        placeholder1.getChildren().clear();
        placeholder2.getChildren().add(component);
        holder.getPanes().add(titledPane);
    });

    return component;
}
```

This new `buildComponent` also adds the `VBox` to the `TitledPane`, so the call to `TitledPane#setContent` in the question should be removed.

I'm still interested to know why this problem occurs, or if there is a way to solve it without wrapping my pane with another pane (`AnchorPane` in my case).